# Rails object relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

Let's say I have a Rails app, and every person that uses it is a square, for example. Most people are only squares, but some people can act as both squares AND triangles.
Triangles would have different (more) attributes than squares, such as different-length sides, type of triangle, etc.
After reading up on `has_many :through`, I'm not sure if I should

- Create a joining table, or
- Just have a few extra attributes that default to nil unless the user is able to act as a triangle.

If I did create a joining table, would I just create joins to triangles on the able squares?
Happy 4th of July!

Comment: I think what you want is [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STI**

Further to `Beerlington`'s comment, you'll probably want to look at [Single Table Inheritance](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) -

```
#app/models/shape.rb
Class Shape < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end

#app/models/user/triangle.rb
Class Triangle < Shape
end

#app/models/users/square.rb
Class Square < Shape
end
```

This should allow you to set:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :shape
   delegate :type, to: :shape, prefix: true #-> allows you to call @user.shape_type
end
```

--

**Associations**

Although I think the associations would likely have to go through the inherited models, this setup will allow you to use the attributes you require in any of the files you need.

For example, with the above setup, you could use the following:

```
@triangles = Triangle.all
@trianbles.each do |triangle|
    triangle.user.name
end
```

Some things you should consider:

> - You want to keep a [single source of truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) (single database table)
> - You want to consider the role of specific shapes in your system (*how*  will you be calling square / triangle)
> - How do the different elements factor into the system (do you call Triangle directly, or indirectly)?

Comment: I think you only need `has_many :users` in the Shape class since the others inherit from this and will have the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you really don't need a `has_many :through` relationship.

I would suggest setting it up like this:

Users

```
 belongs_to :square
 belongs_to :triangle
```

Squares

```
has_many :users
```

Triangles

```
has_many :users
```

These associations would need foreign keys on the Users table.